# Has there been release of Google Maps through Google play services recently?

Tags: android, google-maps

Layer animation functionality in my app broke yesterday for all my previous versions of app.
I have functionality where I set overlay visibility to achieve desired effect. It stopped working yesterday for some reason. It still works on certain devices so I know its not an bug in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Google Play Store page for Maps, it was last updated on 29, August 2014.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps

Google Play services does show an update on 23, September, 2014. 
"4.4.52
- New Street View API
- Updates to activity recognition, Play Games services, and Instant Buy APIs
- Bug fixes"
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

Comment: Yeah...latest update broke my app as it has done couple of times before.